# Parsley.js rails nested attributes not validating

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parsley.js

I have some nested attributes (using simple_fields_for) in a simple_form in rails.

The main form starts like this, and parsley is working fine:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@enquiry, wrapper: :vertical_form, html: {"data-parsley-validate" => ''}) do |f| %>

<%= f.input :total_budget, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Please enter your total or per head budget', label: 'Budget', input_html: { "data-parsley-error-message" => "Please enter a budget", "data-parsley-trigger" => "focusin focusout change" } %>
```

However, in the form further down I have this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :client do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'sign_up_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
```

and the rendered partial is this:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.input :first_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First name' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.input :last_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last name' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :user do |builder| %>

<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= builder.input :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email', required: "true" %>
      </div>
      <% if builder.object.errors[:email] %>
            <%= f.object.errors[:email].join(", ") %>
            <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :phone_number, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Phone number' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= builder.input :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Password', required: "true" %>
      </div>
      <% if builder.object.errors[:password] %>
            <%= f.object.errors[:password].join(", ") %>
            <% end %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

I have tried adding the parsley-data-validation to the simple_fields_for parts in various ways, tried it without, and tried adding parsley validations to the actual fields but that hasn't worked either.

Is there something else I should be doing differently?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong ID for the field I was validating. I still had to use extra js to validate the field; it wasn't picked up by the main HTML: `{"data-parsley-validate" => ''}` in the top of the form.

```
$('#enquiry_client_attributes_user_attributes_email').parsley('validate');
```